# How to find primary key column name in C# or dotnet using dataset?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I wanted to find the primary key column names from dataset obtained, but when I run the application in debug mode, primary key is not getting retrieved. Although there is predefined property in asp.net to get the primary key using *datacolumn*. The code which I have written is attached below.

```
        var dataSetUpdate = new DataSet();

        //Convert Xml string into Dataset/Datatable
        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(tableXml))
        {
            dataSetUpdate.ReadXml(stringReader, XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);
        }

        DataColumn[] PrimaryKeys;
        PrimaryKeys = dataSetUpdate.Tables[0].PrimaryKey;
        string PrimaryKeyColumnName;

        //PrimaryKeys.Length value is coming zero when I checked in debug mode

        for(int j=0;j<PrimaryKeys.Length;j++)   
        {
            PrimaryKeyColumnName = PrimaryKeys[j].ColumnName;
        }
```

Is the way I am obtaining primary key correct?

Comment: The xml file is a text file.  Post the text for more help.

Comment: @jdweng xml string is too large

Comment: Could you post a screenshot or just one row of the table?

Comment: I not sure if a xml file imported to a datatable/dataset will result in a PK setting?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are assigning a single property onto an array object `PrimaryKeys = dataSetUpdate.Tables[0].PrimaryKey;`

try changing that line to `primaryKeys = dataSetUpdate[0]` this is also assumming that your target table is indeed at index 0, otherwise you must just have to check what indexes is your target table in your `dataSetUpdate.Tables`

```
PrimaryKeys = dataSetUpdate.Tables[0]; //primary key property removed here, first debug the dataSet.Tables object and see if there's data at all
    string PrimaryKeyColumnName;// consider camel casing primaryKeyColumn name


    for(int j=0;j<PrimaryKeys.Length;j++)   
    {
        PrimaryKeyColumnName = PrimaryKeys[j].PrimaryKey; //primary key moved here or you can stick with columnName
    }
```